# MYSQL Multiple Table

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I want to use multiple table to get recent post (Q) and user name (handle) but when I am trying to get with this code it is giving error

Table Name **qa_posts** and **qa_users** and need to connect **userid** from **qa_posts** to **handle** from **qa_users**

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts, qa_users
WHERE type="Q" AND qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Error message**

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts, qa_users
WHERE qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 5

Error 1052: Column 'created' in order clause is ambiguous
```

**Actual Code**

```
qa_db_connection();
$query_post = qa_db_query_raw('         
    SELECT *
    FROM qa_posts, qa_users
    WHERE type="Q" AND qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
    ORDER BY created DESC
    LIMIT 5

') or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_post)) {
    echo $row['title'];
    echo '<span style="font-size:65%;font-style:italic">'.$row['created'].'</span>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

See this image for table structure
[image: Table Strucute]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given error cames out when you do have same name column in both table...So you have to specify column name along with table name like in following patter:

```
table_name.column_name
```

So, your query should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts, qa_users
WHERE qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC (or put the ORDER BY qa_users.created DESC if you want to make order by `created` of `qa_users` )
LIMIT 5
```

If you really not desired to have userid of value "qa_users.handle", you should not quote them and should have query like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM qa_posts, qa_users
    WHERE qa_posts.userid = qa_users.userid AND qa_posts.type="Q" 
    ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

You would better to use JOIN in following way:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM qa_posts INNER JOIN qa_users ON qa_posts.userid = qa_users.userid 
    WHERE qa_posts.type="Q" 
    ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks error gone but not rendering anything.. pls check my edited question with full code

Comment: qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle" means? or you want to do like qa_posts.userid = qa_users.handle

Comment: oh wow. I think I should not wrap with quote.. that's what you mean?

Comment: I have added table structure screenshot. please have a look once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16444/discussion-between-lolcoder-and-pixelngrain)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you have you have multiple columns with the name `created` so you need to specify which table the `created` field is coming from to perform the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts, qa_users
WHERE qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts, qa_users
WHERE qa_posts.userid = "qa_users.handle"
ORDER BY qa_users.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Edit #1, without seeing the full table structure it looks like you might want to do this you had the `qa_users.handle` in quotes, these should probably be removed:

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts
INNER JOIN qa_users
   ON qa_posts.userid = qa_users.handle
ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Edit #2 you are joining on the wrong field:

```
SELECT *
FROM qa_posts
INNER JOIN qa_users
   ON qa_posts.userid = qa_users.userid
WHERE qa_posts.type="Q" 
ORDER BY qa_posts.created DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, error gone but it is not rendering any item. I am adding my full code with while loop I request you to please check for better understanding..

Comment: @pixelngrain my suggestion is to try running the query separate first to see if you get results, then attempt to implement it in the rest of your code.

Comment: I actually got post title and created date but now I want to display user name so need to connect both table from qa_posts userid with qa_users handle....Alright let me check the qa_users table output

Comment: @pixelngrain please see my edit, I do not know why you had the `qa_users.handle` in quotes.

Comment: I have added table screenshot pls check it once